blazor bind-Value не работает
Я заменила OnValidSubmit на OnSubmit и увидела, что поля registerData нулевые, несмотря на то что я заполнила вес поля в ui.
  public class RegisterModel : ComponentBase
 {
        [Inject] HttpService httpService { get; set; }
     [Inject] NavigationManager navigationManager { get; set; }
     public RegisterViewModel registerData { get; set; }
     private const int MINIMUM_MULTIPART_UPLOAD_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

     public RegisterModel()
     {
         registerData = new RegisterViewModel();
     }

@inherits RegisterModel
  <Card Shadow="Shadow.Default">
      <CardBody>
          <EditForm Model="@registerData" OnValidSubmit="@Register">
              <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
              <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationSummary></Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationSummary>
              <Field>
                  <FieldLabel>
                      Your Email
                  </FieldLabel>
                  <FieldBody>
                      <TextEdit @bind-Value="@registerData.Email"  Placeholder="name@blazorise.com" Role="TextRole.Email" />
                  </FieldBody>
              </Field>

              <Field>
                  <FieldLabel>
                      Gender
                  </FieldLabel>
                  <FieldBody>
                      <RadioGroup @bind-Value="@registerData.Gender" TValue="Gender_type" Name="gender">
                          @foreach (var val in Gender_type.GetValues(typeof(Gender_type)).Cast<Gender_type>())
                          {
                              <Radio TValue="Gender_type" Value="@val">@(val.ToString())</Radio>
                          }
                      </RadioGroup>
                  </FieldBody>
                  
              </Field>

